# How to reference result from previous 2 column like Excel formular

Tags: sql, t-sql

```
SELECT   
Answer_Code AS C0,   
Text AS C1,  
Price AS C2,   
sum(case when Response like '%PAID%' then 1 else 0 end) AS C3,
C2 * C3 AS 'Total'    --Invalid column name 'C2'.--
FROM TableA
```

How to reference C2 and C3, then do multiplication in that position ?

Any techniques ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use inner-select:

```
SELECT *, C2 * C3 As Total
FROM (
    SELECT   
        Answer_Code AS C0,   
        Text AS C1,  
        Price AS C2,   
        sum(case when Response like '%PAID%' then 1 else 0 end) AS C3,
    FROM TableA) DT;
```

or use a CTE like this:

```
;WITH t AS (
    SELECT   
        Answer_Code AS C0,   
        Text AS C1,  
        Price AS C2,   
        sum(case when Response like '%PAID%' then 1 else 0 end) AS C3,
    FROM TableA)
SELECT *, C2 * C3 As Total
FROM t;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `with` clause or a `sub query`.

```
;with tmp_tbl as (
    SELECT   
    Answer_Code AS C0,   
    Text AS C1,  
    Price AS C2,   
    sum(case when Response like '%PAID%' then 1 else 0 end) AS C3
    --C2 * C3 AS 'Total'    --Invalid column name 'C2'.--
    FROM TableA
)
select
    C0,
    C1,
    C2,
    C3,
    C2 * C3 AS 'Total'
from tmp_tbl;
```